# How to store a *signed* 24 bit int into another variable?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I need to encode a 24 bit integer into the end of 32 bit int.

(the first byte contains other data, the other three are empty for use by the 24 bit int)

I already have a `SET_BYTE` macro, and I can successfully do the following for *unsigned* 24 bit values:

```
SET_BYTE(DEST, START_BYTE_INDEX,   (uint8_t)(VALUE)); 
SET_BYTE(DEST, START_BYTE_INDEX+1, (uint8_t)(VALUE >> 8)); 
SET_BYTE(DEST, START_BYTE_INDEX+2, (uint8_t)(VALUE >> 16));
```

What I'm stuck on is that I'm not quite sure how to modify this approach to work for **signed** 24 bit integers?

---

If I attempt to store the value -22 with the above (modified to use `int8_t`, obviously), for example, I get the following byte values:

```
-22
-1
-1
```

which read back as these (if I do `<<0`, `<<8` and `<<16` when reading):

```
-22
-256
-65536
```

I'm assuming I just need to totally avoid these shifts with signed values, but I'm not sure what the correct approach is?

Comment: This question should be tagged _either_ C or C++, __not__ both. The answers are different for the two.

Comment: Easiest way to do it is to left shift 8 bit then right shift 8 bit, then 24 bit signed int will be sign-extended to 32 bit. However that approach is potentially UB according to the C standard. A similar solution is 1) convert 24 bit signed integer to 32 bit unsigned int, then left shift 8 bit, then convert to 32 bit signed int, then right shift 8 bit. This avoids UB but requires the signed numbers be 2's complement to get the desired result.

Comment: @c650 I am using both C++ and C externs so answers applicable to either are useful to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a ≥32-bit structure (as you said, you have other data in the last byte) use struct bitfields:

```
struct Packed
{
    uint8_t byte;
    int32_t smaller : 24;
};
```

alternatively, you can abuse [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset):

```
struct fake_int24_t
{
    static_assert(sizeof(int) <= sizeof(unsigned long long), "");

    bitset<24> data;

    operator int() const {
        return data.to_ulong() - (1 << 23);
    }

    fake_int24_t& operator=(int val) {
        assert(val >= -(1 << 23)); // 2's complement
        assert(val < (1 << 23));

        data = bitset<24>(val + (1 << 23));

        return *this;
    }
};
```

[live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/dzjfue8Mt8AScFkK)

`sizeof(fake_int24_t)` doesn't have to be 3, though, so you might want to stick a normal integer in there.

Comment: I think that bit fields are the most simple way to accomplish the requested behaviour.

Comment: I'll use the struct bitfields, thanks. I had avoided this feature because I presumed it was specific to C99 etc. I wasn't aware it was also valid C++

I could have used bitset (and will keep that approach in mind) but yeah - the bitfields are super easy to understand + read by comparison

Comment: @c650 If the endian of `SET_BYTE()` as posted defines the required endian, a bit field may not have a matching endian.  Yet a bit field makes a lot of sense if `int` size, endian, alignment issues do not mess it up.

Answer (score 1):

> to encode a 24 bit integer into the end of 32 bit int.

OP's existing macros implies the 24-bit *unsigned* type is store in little endian - see following.
Let us assume the 24-bit *signed* uses the same endian and the common 2's complement integer encoding.

```
SET_BYTE(DEST, START_BYTE_INDEX,   (uint8_t)(VALUE)); 
SET_BYTE(DEST, START_BYTE_INDEX+1, (uint8_t)(VALUE >> 8)); 
...
```

Note, we do not know the endian of the 32-bit `int` nor its encoding (2's , 1's or sign-mag).  As it turns out, we do not need that information.

```
struct signed_24_bit {
  uint8_t other_data;
  uint8_t use_by_the_24_bit_int[3];
};

int decode_24_bit_integer(struct signed_24_bit x) {
  int32_t y = x.use_by_the_24_bit_int[0] // 1st byte of int24
      + (x.use_by_the_24_bit_int[1] * 0x100)
      + (x.use_by_the_24_bit_int[2] * 0x10000);

  // If y > INT24_MAX
  if (y > 0x7FFFFF) y -= 0x1000000;
  return y;
}

// Assume `x` is in range of `int24_t`
struct signed_24_bit encode_24_bit_integer(int x) {
  if ( x < 0) x += 0x1000000;
  struct signed_24_bit y = { 0, { x, x/0x100, x/0x10000 } };
  return y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a sign-magnitude representation in the 24-bit part:

```
int value = -22;
unsigned long target = std::abs(value) & ((1 << 23) - 1);
if (value < 0)
    target |= 1 << 23;
```

To extract the value, just reverse the process:

```
int result = target & ((1 << 23) - 1);
if (target & (1 << 23))
    result = -result;
```

(caution: not tested)